# Why is JQuery casting a string to _id for Mongodb in this? (Please read EDIT)

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a route that adds an image (a meme) like this:

```
// add new image by URL
app.post('/api/addMeme', function (req, res) {
    var meme = new Meme({
        title: req.body.title.trim().toLowerCase(),
        image: req.body.image,
        meta: {
            votes: 0,
            favs: 0
        },
        related: []
    });

    // Save meme to database
    meme.save(function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        Meme.find({}, function (err, meme) {
            if (err) throw err;
            io.emit('new meme', meme);
        });
        res.send('Succesfully inserted meme.');
    });
});
```

It takes the only two attribute `title` and `image` given by client side `ajax` and add it to my `Mongodb` database named `Meme`. Emit the updated database using `socket.io`. Both `title` and `image` are `String` type. `image` is suppose to be an URL to an image.

Now, I'm not ashamed to admit it, but my friend trolled my site and sent `image = "www.pornhub.com"` to this route and it crashed my database/site. Whenever I go and try to retrieve the image by its `_id`, I get the error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "www.pornhub.com" at path "_id" for model "meme"
```

---

EDIT: it looks like the error is actually coming from the route

```
app.post('/api/vote', function(req, res){
    Meme.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.body.id}, {$inc : {'meta.votes' : 1}}, {new: true}, function (err, meme) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!meme) return res.send('No meme found with that ID.');
        io.emit('new vote', meme);
        res.send('Succesfully voted meme.');
    });
});
```

where a `POST` request is updating the database, and there's a cast error where the `_id` is given as a string?

The client side script that's doing this is

```
$("#vote").click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/api/vote',
        data: {
            id: App.meme._id
        },
        success: function (data, status) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

where `App` is a `Express-state` exposed data for which `meme`, the database, lives under.

But this error ONLY occurs on the object with `image = "www.pornhub.com"`. My guess is that somewhere in the HTML, a cross-site `href` is visiting `www.pornhub.com` and somehow `App` is getting distorted? It doesn't fully make sense why `id: App.meme._id` would give `www.pornhub.com` as its value.

Comment: The error cannot come from "this code" since there is nothing that attempts to send the `_id` property. That's a mongoose validation cast error where the "string" which is attempted to be placed in the `_id` is not valid. But it's simply not from this code. I suspect it's actually being thrown where the value is coming from `req.params.id` and you are using something like `findByIdAndUpdate()` with the "upsert" option set. That's typically where you would end up attempting to set an `_id` value. But mongoose won't persist it to the database because it's not valid, and will error.

Comment: You can try to load that link first to make sure it is a image

Comment: @Neil Lunn care the elaborate?

Comment: What's not elaborated on? You're looking for the source of the error in the wrong code. This is not where it is coming from. Look for occurrences of something like what I pointed out in your code instead.

Comment: That error is not related to the title of this post and it is not the point here. What OP needs is a way to check if a link is a remote image file.

Comment: To detect the file MIME type, have a try on this package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/mmmagic

Comment: @Neil Lunn and everyone, I updated my question, and it seems like the issue is weirder than I thought.

Comment: also updated the title to be more relevant.

Comment: So you actually want to stop the "client" from sending the data which would be invalid in the first place? Is that the actual question? I actually still don't get how that could be in the `id` property in the first place. Surely you want the database `id` value and that should be in the page data. So why are you letting any code overwrite that? Seems you have bigger problems here.

Comment: Well yes. I need to do that FIRST, but then I also need to check for valid image URLs after that's fixed. Apologies for all the confusions.

Comment: Look up as the comment was edited. In short it makes no sense at all that you are allowing anything to overwrite that value in the client. You're thinking through this incorrectly. You don't need to "check an image", you simply should not be overwriting the supplied value. Something bad in your client scripting is doing this.

Comment: @Neil Lunn I'm sorry, my understanding of webdev is very limited. I'm not sure how I'm overwriting `id`. `id` is part of `req.body` I want to pass in to my api to update my database. Is `data: {id: App.meme._id }` overwriting anything? `App.meme` exists with `_id` as an entry, not `id`.